# Issue with displaying image png with php

Tags: php

I have an issue with displaying an image stored on my debian server outside the path accessible to the webserver in order to keep it safe. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2DR4.png) a link to the expected results, as well as the relevant PHP code below:

```
header("content-type: image/png");
if (isset($_POST['mot_de_passe']) AND $_POST['mot_de_passe'] ==  "superPassword") {
    // If password is valid
    $filename = "/home/image/test.png";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
    echo $contents;
} else {
    // If password is invalid
    echo '<p>Mot de passe incorrect</p>';
}
```

Comment: What does the `v` flag do in [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)? Btw, there is also [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Comment: it's a little error, but didn't change the result after fixing it, and I tried file_get_content and  it show the same.

Comment: Well, `header( "Content-Type: image/png" ); readfile( "/home/image/test.php" );` should work fine - if that file exists! There *is* a difference between *file path* `/home/image/test.png` and `<img src="/home/image/test.png">`: the latter is below the web-server's DocumentRoot.

Answer (score 0):

This below statement should be first line of your script. Means before any html output. That solves the issue

```
 header("content-type: image/png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  `r+`

```
fopen($filename, "r+");
```

Because you say Debian I have the question: **PHP and httpd have access to read that directory(somewhere in my debian) and file (image)?**

`chmod`

Comment: To be sure, I have done a chmod 777 -R on the image directory.

Comment: and to   image too?

`cd /home/some_dir` and `chmod -R 777  *` . You controlled the perrmisions after to dir and image file?

Comment: result of `ls -n` of both directory and file : 

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 33 71658 Feb  6 12:42 test.png`
`drwxrwxrwx 2    0  0 4096 Feb  6 13:44 image`